# Enum inside enum in Groovy loops forever, why?

Tags: groovy, enums

Assume the following code:

```
enum Color {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
    enum Type {
        RGBA,
        RGB,
        BGR
    }
    String getHex() {
        //something here
        return "#F00"
    }
    Type getType() {
        //something here
        return Type.RGB
    }
}
println Color.RED.type.name()
```

I thought nested `enum` were possible, but if you try to run this piece of code with groovy (using 2.4.13), it seems it loops forever and it never execute or compile it.

If I take the enum `Type` outside, it works fine.

Why does that happen? Is there any reference which explains why it fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GROOVY-4438

It is fixed if you use the new "parrot" parser which is optional in Groovy 2.6+ and enabled by default in Groovy 3

Comment: Isn't Parrot only available in 2.6 (off by default)?

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!